# Leafleat Filter two geojson files and array string include separator

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, leaflet, geojson

I'd like to filter an array of strings from two sources inside a leaflet code.
How can i split a string and filter it.

The Tags in my geojson have separate keywords and i will use i input field to filter and display only the coordinates with the keyword.

here my sources

json_one.json

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -90.072755,
          29.961909
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "French Quarter",
        "Tags": "Louisiana, New Orleans, French Quarter, Hwy-61, Mississippi River, I-12, Outlet Shopping"
        }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -95.053883,
          29.796708
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Leisure",
        "Tags": "Houston, Texas, I-45, Outlet Shopping, I-10"
        }
    }

  ]
}
```

and
json_next.json

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -80.941429,
          25.138486
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Flamingo",
        "Tags": "Outlet Shopping, Louisiana"
        }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -112.121,
          36.051
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Grand",
        "Tags": "Louisiana"
        }
    }

  ]
}
```

How can i filter the properties.Tags by "Outlet Shopping" with this leaflet code

```
var one = L.geoJson.ajax("json_one.json", {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng)
                    .bindTooltip("<b>" + feature.properties.name + '</b><br />')
            ;}
        });

var next = L.geoJson.ajax("json_next.json", {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng)
                    .bindTooltip("<b>" + feature.properties.name + '</b><br />')
            ;}
        });
```

Please help me, thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Thanks for pushing in the right direction ;)